# Python "list index out of range" error on proven index

Tags: python-3.x

To start, I want to create a function to read each file in a folder, removes the extension, appends them into an empty list and print the first ten entries.

```
def directory_contents(directory):

    import os

    dl = os.listdir(directory)

    files = []

    for file in dl:
        filename = os.path.splitext(file)

        files.append(filename[0])

    print(files[:10])
```

Next, I will split each filename it into separate parts and put them into individual lists. I will iterate over each file and put append each part of the filename into the appropriate list. To finish, I will merge each list to make a DataFrame/table.

```
def split_filename(directory):
    import os

    dl = os.listdir(directory)

    Index_0 = []
    Index_1 = []
    Index_2 = []
    Index_3 = []
    Index_4 = []

    for file in dl:
        filename = os.path.splitext(file)
        no_ext = filename[0].split('_')
        i_0 = no_ext[0]
        i_1 = no_ext[1]
        i_2 = no_ext[2]
        i_3 = no_ext[3]
        i_4 = no_ext[4]

        Index_0.append(i_0)
        Index_1.append(i_1)
        Index_2.append(i_2)
        Index_3.append(i_3)
        Index_4.append(i_4)

    print(Index_0[:10])
    print(Index_1[:10])
    print(Index_2[:10])
    print(Index_3[:10])
    print(Index_4[:10])
```

As you can see in the above function, I created empty lists to hold each part of the filename after is split by its index. The fore loop iterates over every file in the directory (dl) and removes the file extension by using the splittext() method. I then use the first index created but the splitext as it holds the information I want to split again to access each part. The split() method with an underscore then separates the filename into individual parts which are saved as separate variables. Next, we append each variable to the appropriate list and print the list after everything is complete.

Let us define the directory, and see what the output of the functions.

```
directory = './Test/Data/'
directory_contents(directory)
```

Output:
['f0_f1_f2_f3_f4', 'd0_d1_d2_d3_d4', 'i0_i1_i2_i3_i4', 'j0_j1_j2_j3_j4', 'b0_b1_b2_b3_b4', 'e0_d1_d2_d3_d4', 'g0_g1_g2_g3_g4', 'h0_h1_h2_h3_h4', 'a0_a1_a2_a3_a4', 'c0_c1_c2_c3_c4']

That worked perfectly. Now let's see if it works on a folder full of files I want to analyze.

```
directory = './WBV/database/WBV/cmj/pre/0 Hz/'
directory_contents(directory)
```

Output:
['P05_0Hz_Pre_CMJ_T02', 'P24_0Hz_Pre_CMJ_T03', 'P17_0Hz_Pre_CMJ_T01', 'P19_0Hz_Pre_CMJ_T01', 'P14_0Hz_Pre_CMJ_T02', 'P13_0Hz_Pre_CMJ_T02', 'P02_0Hz_Pre_CMJ_T01', 'P26_0Hz_Pre_CMJ_T01', 'P14_0Hz_Pre_CMJ_T01', 'P06_0Hz_Pre_CMJ_T02']

That's good, it reads all of the files in the folder and not in numerical order. Let's see if it can split all of the filenames.

```
split_filename(directory)
```

Output:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-22-392a30f7485a> in <module>()
----> 1 split_filename(directory)

<ipython-input-17-d53a23fcf079> in split_filename(directory)
     15         i_0 = no_ext[0]
     16         i_1 = no_ext[1]
---> 17         i_2 = no_ext[2]
     18         i_3 = no_ext[3]
     19         i_4 = no_ext[4]

IndexError: list index out of range
```

This is where things stop making sense. Why is it throwing an index error when the filenames from the text folder and the research folder have the same format? Let make another function to list out the indices for each part of one filename.

```
import os
fn = os.path.splitext('./WBV/database/WBV/cmj/pre/0 Hz/P05_0Hz_Pre_CMJ_T02.exp')
f0 = fn[0].split('_')
for i in f0:
    print(f0.index(i), i)
```

Output:
0 ./WBV/database/WBV/cmj/pre/0 Hz/P05
1 0Hz
2 Pre
3 CMJ
4 T02

Besides the path to the file being part of the first index, it states that 'Pre' is at index 2. So why is it throwing me an error when I call index 2? Any recommendations on how I can resolve this error would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code seems correct to me.

I'd suggest to change the directory_contents function to show all content, not only the first ten items, so you can check for hidden files. If you're on Windows, your folder will propably contain some hidden `desktop.ini` which will be listed in `os.listdir()`. This, of course, won't work well with your program...

If that doesn't help, please add a `print(no_ext)` in your for loop, to see what filename actually caused the error. (Your print functions are at the very end of your code, so the error can appear anywhere in the list, not neccessarily on the first entry!)

Comment: I had a hidden folder that I was not aware of, and it was pulling that folders name. I hadn't thought of a hidden folder being an issue.

Thank you for that very insightful, yet simple suggestion.

Best